# sideloading gapps after cm13 install

Tags: cyanogenmod

I've tried to use cm recovery to flash the Gapps package, but it can't find the zip.
I get an error "invalid argument" 
I have tried flashing through ADB also, but once in recovery mode, the pc can no longer see the device ( nexus 6)

Comment: Have you tried with a different recovery? Try it now if you haven't. Which GApps are you using? From where have you downloaded it?

Comment: If you need Gapps for CyanogenMod 13, chek please this link: http://cyanmod.pl/download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-nano-20151207.zip They should work

Comment: your installation might be broken, download latest Nightly-build, clear caches install Android 6.0 again, then for gapps use link above

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because CM nightly builds appear to be shipping with a nightly build of CM recovery ([see it yourself](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?device=shamu)) and issues related to nightly build of a software are not helpful to this site in long run. Refer to http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2077/96277 for details.

Answer (score 1):

Best way: First, install TWRP because CWM doesn't support it, then wipe data and cache. Be sure to take a backup. Now install CM13 and GApps. Reboot and it will work smoothly.

Comment: You didn't mention that TWRP also has stable and nightly builds and it is not free from bugs either. It would help if you provide the version of a stable build of TWRP meant for OP's device.